# SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser Unrecognized Expression

Tags: spservices

Console:

```
Sizzle.error                     @ jquery-1.9.0.js:4411
tokenize                         @ jquery-1.9.0.js:5057
select                           @ jquery-1.9.0.js:5439
Sizzle                           @ jquery-1.9.0.js:3984
find                             @ jquery-1.9.0.js:5553
init                             @ jquery-1.9.0.js:179
jQuery                           @ jquery-1.9.0.js:53
V.fn.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser @ jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js:19
(anonymous function)             @ EditForm.aspx?ID=8&Source=[source]
dispatch                         @ jquery-1.9.0.js:3045
elemData.handle                  @ jquery-1.9.0.js:2721
```

Hi, I am having trouble using SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser function. The script containing my code

```
$.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "EMail", debug: false });
```

is returning

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <!DOCTYPE html...</html>.
```

The error is displaying the whole html markup of the page. The .js file is added to the form page using Content Editor. Other files referenced inside my .js are:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.5326.1210/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
```

I am also auto populating people picker fields within the form using hardcoded emails ([link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0e70e629-649e-4313-ab15-0e6df4975eee/how-to-populate-current-login-user-and-display-into-people-picker-field-with-auto-resolve-?forum=sharepointgeneral)) and it works just fine.

Anyone encountered this error? Please share your thoughts. TIA

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parens after the $.  Try changing this:

```
$.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "EMail", debug: false });
```

To this:

```
$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "EMail", debug: false });
```

Hope that helps!